# K-Fold Cross-Validation With Only a Low Identification Accuracy for the First Fold

Tags: machine-learning

I am using K-Fold cross validation from `sklearn.model_selection` for evaluating the performance of my model. K=10 and the K-fold cross-validation is set as:

```
kfcv=Kfold(n_splits=10, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
```

The result of the first fold is 70% while remaining 9 folds are 100%. I have set random state to another value (such as 50), the same problem.

Why is the high discrepancy only with the first fold? I have used 5 fold and the same problem with the first fold. I expect that other folds should also reflects a decrease since the division is random and I also set shuffle to be true.

Is there anything am doing wrongly? If not, what would be the likely explanation for this?

Thanks.

Comment: How many "examples" are there that the K-Fold operates upon?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Fine-tuned on a small dataset with 2420 examples.

Comment: And this discrepancy is consistent across more than one runs?

Comment: not consistent. Only with the first fold (70%) while others gave me 100%. Why the discrepancy is only with the first fold and other folds gave good results? Is this strange and if not, what could be the likely explanation for this?

Comment: If you run K-fold once, it would run the computation partitioning the data in one way. If you run it again, the data will be partitioned in a different way. Is this behaviour that you report consistent between runs?

Comment: Yes, the accuracy after every run and only the first fold is low (70%) and others 9 folds are 100%. The code for the division in a loop is like this:                                                                                                                                                                                                 
kfcv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
for trn_idx, tst_idx in kfcv.split(data):
    x_train = data[trn_idx, 
    y_train1 = target[trn_idx]
    x_test =data[tst_idx, 
    y_test1 = target[tst_idx]